# Get higher resolution pygame

Tags: python, pygame, resolution

I am trying to make a game in python and pygame. I want to make a game with decent resolution, but I can't get higher resolution, any ways?

```
import pygame
import time
import random
import os

pygame.init()
height = 600
width = 800
window = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))

white = 255,255,255
black = 0,0,0
red = 255,0,0
blue = 0,0,255

def update():
    pygame.display.update()
def game():
    stop_game = False
    while not stop_game:
        window.fill(white)
        loaded_image = pygame.image.load("Player.png")
        loaded_image = pygame.transform.scale(loaded_image,(150,150))
        window.blit(loaded_image,(0,0))
        update()
game()
```

Comment: is changing the width and height variables not working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print pygame.display.list_modes()
```

This will list the available display modes for you.  Mine goes up to (2646, 1024).